# How to remove the last line in a text file

Tags: vb.net, filesystems

Is there way to remove the last 14 characters (last line) from a 1 MB text file without reading in and writing out every single line?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to delete the first and last lines from a text file in visual basic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099505/how-to-delete-the-first-and-last-lines-from-a-text-file-in-visual-basic)

Comment: The question is "without reading in and writing out every single line".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [FileStream's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0bs3w9t.aspx) .Seek and .SetLength methods.

Comment: Fantastic !! Actually, it looks like I can just use fs.SetLength(fs.Length-16).  I can't figure out why there are so many posts dealing with this issue and so many answers that insist on reading and writing the whole file.

Answer (score 0):

You can first check length of last line and then delete the number of characters Last Line has using fs.setlength
This way you don't have to use loop and your work is done pretty efficiently

```
Dim lines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines(f)
    Dim L As String = lines.Last.Length.ToString
    Dim f As String = "C:\New Text Document.txt"

        Dim fs As New FileStream(f, FileMode.Open, 
        FileAccess.ReadWrite)
        fs.SetLength(fs.Length - L)
        fs.Close()
```